# typo3 backend: Attach a label to extension placeholder

Tags: typo3, typo3-4.5

In typo3 4.7 (cannot upgrade this instance) I often need to put a few lightweight extensions on one page. In the backend, I quickly lose track of all these extensions.

I wonder if there is a way to attach a label to such an extension placeholder.

I want a similar functionality as the freetext field: **"Name (not visible in frontend)"**  which is available for "Default HTML"  content elements, but not for "Plugin" content elements.

Here is an illustration of what I mean. In the backend, WEB Module/Page, editing any page:
[image]

... or can they?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

The "Behavior" tab contains a deprecated textfield **"Plugin Mode"** that can be used as a label. Internally the value from this field will be stored in a column called "CODE".

[image]

According to the context-sensitive help for this field, it can function aas a label unless the plugin uses this value.

And indeed, the text from the 2nd red box above appears in the backend and facilitates orientation.

[image]

But here I am talking about my own extensions where I know that this field is unused.